# Find memory efficient data structure in python

Tags: python

I need to transfer a large number of  python list through loop,

in a long running python process (> 10 days)
such as

```
for i in range(0, 10000000)
  ll = getlist_string(10000)
  ...

  json.dump(ll, dir)
```

However, list are memory hungry and even gc.collect() 
cannot release memory to OS.

Is there a memory benefit of replacement list by string or binary string ?
(string being contiguous in memory...)

Comment: Have you considered changing `getlist_string` to return a generator instead of a list?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: need to convert the string into json (ie string).